# BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (hresult 0x8007010b)

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

> Trying to mount a db into a mssql docker container

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngP@ssw0rd!
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
EXPOSE 1433

COPY mydb.mdf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf
COPY mydb_log.ldf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf

ENTRYPOINT /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

> EDIT

It seems that the only thing that prevents the image from running as a container is when I add those two `COPY` instructions within the `Dockerfile`.  Everything works fine when I remove the two `COPY`.

In fact, it says that it can't copy `c:\tempdata\master.mdf` to `/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf`.  But why is that?

Lately, when

> Structure

All files are in the same folder on my local machine.

```
myfolder
    /Dockerfile
    /mydb.mdf
    /mydb_log.ldf
```

> Environment

- Windows 10 for Workstation
- Docker Desktop 4.5.1 (74721) (

  Engine 20.10.12,

  Compose 1.29.2,

  Kubernetes 1.22.5,

  Snyk 1.827.0,

  Credential Helper 0.6.4)
- Visual Studio Code 1.67.2

> Error obtained

The image is built in a flawless fashion, letting believe everything's fine.  But when I run it, I get an error:

```
ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x8007010b)
```

To run the image, I type the following command:

```
docker run -p 1433:1433 myimage
```

or even

```
docker run myimage
```

and both fashions creates the same error.

When I type in:

```
docker images
```

I can see:

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG             IMAGE ID           CREATED           SIZE
myimage                    latest          ffc13a86b57b       28 seconds ago    2.83GB
```

Which confirms that the image is correctly created.

> FINAL EDIT

I thought I would share the resulting `Dockerfile` and final solution.

**The Goal**

*The goal was to take a client's database MDF and LDF files in SQL Server and mount them in a Docker Container to avoid the process of installing a local SQL Server instance which I don't really need.*

**Lesson LEARNED**

As @AlwaysLearning states, the `COPY` instructions are processed through the `root` user of the container, hence taking ownership over the `/var/opt/mssql`.  Doing exactly as she/he said solved the problem.  So folder's ownership needs to be given back to `mssql` user as described in @AlwaysLearning's answer.  BIG THX!

**Final Solution**

The final solution is to be able to mount/attach the client's database files to the containerized instance of SQL Server.  For that to work, I needed to write a shell script which does just that.

*attach-db.sh*

```
sleep 15s

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S . -U sa -P $tr0ngP@ssw0rd! -Q "CREATE DATABASE [mydb] ON (FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf'),(FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf') FOR ATTACH"
```

This comes from here:  [Attaching databases via a dockerfile](https://dbafromthecold.com/2018/12/11/attaching-databases-via-a-dockerfile-update/)

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=$tr0ngP@ssw0rd!

COPY mydb.mdf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf
COPY mydb_log.ldf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf
COPY attach-db.sh /var/opt/mssql/data/attach-db.sh

ENTRYPOINT /var/opt/mssql/data/attach-db.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

**Running the built image**

```
docker run -p 1433:1433 --hostname mydb myimage
```

**Connecting to database**

[Download and install Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) is required to connect to a containerized SQL Server instance.

Comment: Aside... `ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433` and `EXPOSE 1433` are redundant because they are the defaults for the image you are pulling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the logs for the Docker container you'll see that the complete error message is:

```
2022-06-09 00:12:57.28 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
2022-06-09 00:12:57.33 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  5(Access is denied.)
ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070005)
```

This happens because the Dockerfile `COPY` actions are performed as the `root` user which leave the file system objects owned by the `root` user as seen with:

```bash
$ ls -la /var/opt/mssql/data
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun  9 00:12 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root root 4096 Jun  9 00:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 00:06 mydb.mdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 00:06 mydb_log.ldf
```

The SQL Server service itself is executed using the `mssql` user so now it doesn't have access to the `/var/opt/mssql/data` directory to add its own files. You can correct that situation by changing the ownership of the files and directories to the `mssql` user, i.e.:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngP@ssw0rd!

COPY mydb.mdf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf
COPY mydb_log.ldf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf

USER root
RUN chown -R mssql:root /var/opt/mssql
USER mssql
```

Now the container will start successfully and you can see that the SQL Server service was able to copy its bootstrap files into the `/var/opt/mssql/data` directory:

```bash
$ ls -la /var/opt/mssql/data
total 81168
drwxr-xr-x 1 mssql root     4096 Jun  9 00:23 .
drwxrwx--- 1 mssql root     4096 Jun  9 00:23 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root      256 Jun  9 00:23 Entropy.bin
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  4653056 Jun  9 00:23 master.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  2097152 Jun  9 00:23 mastlog.ldf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  8388608 Jun  9 00:23 model.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root 14090240 Jun  9 00:23 model_msdbdata.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root   524288 Jun  9 00:23 model_msdblog.ldf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root   524288 Jun  9 00:23 model_replicatedmaster.ldf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  4653056 Jun  9 00:23 model_replicatedmaster.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  8388608 Jun  9 00:23 modellog.ldf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root 14090240 Jun  9 00:23 msdbdata.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root   524288 Jun  9 00:23 msdblog.ldf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mssql root        0 Jun  9 00:06 mydb.mdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mssql root        0 Jun  9 00:06 mydb_log.ldf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  8388608 Jun  9 00:23 tempdb.mdf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  8388608 Jun  9 00:23 tempdb2.ndf
-rw-r----- 1 mssql root  8388608 Jun  9 00:23 templog.ldf
```

**Edit:**

It's worth pointing out that the Dockerfile `COPY` command can also set owner+group attributes on-the-fly whilst copying files into the image. This then alleviates the need to switch to `USER root` and back to `USER mssql` so as to apply `chown` manually, i.e.:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngP@ssw0rd!

COPY --chown=mssql:root mydb.mdf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb.mdf
COPY --chown=mssql:root mydb_log.ldf /var/opt/mssql/data/mydb_log.ldf
```